# remove extra white space and add space after specific symbol

Tags: r, string, data-manipulation

I have a character vector and I want to remove extra white spaces and leave a space after `;` many thanks in advance,

```
text <- "Mezgebo Gk;     Ymesel T;Tegegne G"
```

I tired these

```
text <- gsub("\\s+"," ",text)
text <- sub(";", "; ", text)
```

Expected outcome

```
"Mezgebo Gk; Ymesel T; Tegegne G"
```

Comment: try `gsub(";\\s*", "; ", text)`. This substitutes all `;` and following white spaces (0 or more than 0)  with `;` and only one space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the code below

```
gsub("(?<=;)(\\s+)?"," ",text,perl = TRUE)
```

which gives

```
[1] "Mezgebo Gk; Ymesel T; Tegegne G"
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a handy function specifically for removing extra spaces irrespective of its location within the string:

```
library(tidyverse)
str_squish("Mezgebo Gk;     Ymesel T;Tegegne G")
```

```
[1] "Mezgebo Gk; Ymesel T;Tegegne G"
```